# Is this capacitor 1.2volt or 5volt rated?

Tags: capacitor, datasheet, documentation

I am having trouble understanding this.  The document says that this cap is rated at 5volt, but it says that it will break down above 1.2volts...

Can someone please take a look and tell me what they mean?

http://www.arborsci.com/Data_Sheets/P6-8012_DS.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Each cell breaks down at 1.2V. The datasheet says that the capacitor is composed of a number of small cells. Reading between the lines, that number must be at least 5, and they are connected in series.

Answer (score 1):

The paper explains it: The capacitor is made up of multiple (five?) cells in series, so that each cell sees less than 1.2V.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with these caps, but I understand the document as follows:

Each cell withstands up to a maximum of 1.2V. The capacitor itself consists of "individual cells [that] are stacked in series". The voltage is split accross the individual cells when u apply 5V to the capacitor so no cell experience more than 1.2V (when operating at the rated voltage of 5V).